# Migrating data from old container to new partitioned container using change feed

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

1.Is using azure cosmosdb changefeed right approach, to migrate data from old containers to new partitioned containers?
2.Will azure cosmosdb changefeed have documents which are not at all modified even once till now?
3.If above are true, what are the steps involved in migrating data using azure cosmosdb change feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use Change Feed to achieve all this. Cosmos DB has several options to [consume the Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed), one of them is [using Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions).

If you go with the Functions option, you can quickly do a simple migration mixing the [Cosmos DB Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger) (with `StartFromBeginning` to `true`) and the [Cosmos DB Output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#output) like so:

```
[FunctionName("Migration")]
public static async Task Run(
    [CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "your-source-database",
        collectionName: "your-source-collection",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "Connection-String-Setting-Name-For-Source-Account",
        StartFromBeginning = true,
        CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
    )] IReadOnlyList<Document> source,
    [CosmosDB(
        databaseName: "your-destination-database",
        collectionName: "your-destination-collection",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "Connection-String-Setting-Name-For-Destination-Account" // In case your destination is on a different account, otherwise, it could be the same value as the Trigger
    )] IAsyncCollector<Document> destination,
    ILogger log)
{
    foreach(var doc in source){
          await destination.AddAsync(doc);
    }
}
```

There are some optimizations that can be applied for Multi master or geo-distributed applications (like using `PreferredLocations` if your Function is running on a different region).

Keep in mind that the Function acts as a **live** migration. It will start migrating documents that exist before it was deployed, and then it will continue to migrate new documents while it keeps running if your source collection keeps getting insert/updates.

If what you are needing is a **cold** migration, you could also use the [Data Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/import-data)

Comment: Thanks, you reply is useful. 1. The sample code shows we can migrate data from only one container at a time, is there any way to migrate of data of 10 different source container to its respective destination/new container? 2. Out of migration context - consider "StartFromBeginning = true" attribute is removed from trigger attribute then function will be trigger for only future updates/inserts after deployment during which the past updates/inserts won't be considered, is that correct? 3.is change feed will be used for migrating from a single partition collection to a multi-partition collection?

Comment: 1 - No present way to migrate all containers. 2 - Correct, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---configuration. 3 - You can use it to migrate from a single partition to multi-partition collection, yes

Comment: In Destination database we will require this "CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true" . I don't understand why we need that in source? in source it should be LeaseCollectionName = "leases" ... correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: No you do not need CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists in the destination, because the Lease is only used on the CosmosDBTrigger (source). CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists is completely optional, you can choose to create the lease collection manually.