# not able to migrated between 2 cosmos containers

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to migrate between data between 2 containers with option `StartFromBeginning =true`. while migrating I am also making a small modification to the document also. When I add this logic I live sync between collections is not working. I had used [Migrating data from old container to new partitioned container using change feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041986/migrating-data-from-old-container-to-new-partitioned-container-using-change-feed) as reference which works. After deploying there seems to be no error but. How can I check what I am doing wrong. I have also enabled application insights.

```
namespace CosmosContainerMigration.Trigger
{
    public class ContainerMigration
    {
        private IUpdatedDocument updatedDocument;


        public ContainerMigration(IUpdatedDocument updatedDocument)
        {
            this.updatedDocument = updatedDocument;
        }

        [FunctionName("CosmosContainerMigration")]
        public async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "%SourceDatabaseName%", 
            collectionName: "%ContainerName%",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "connectionString",
            StartFromBeginning =true,
            LeaseCollectionName ="%ContainerLeaseName%",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> source,
            [CosmosDB(databaseName:"%TargetDatabaseName%",
            collectionName:"%ContainerName%",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "connectionString")]IAsyncCollector<Document> destination,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + source.Count);

            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                try
                {
                    Document updatedItem = await this.updatedDocument.Update(item);

                    await destination.AddAsync(updatedItem);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Failed document ", item.Id);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions in your App Insights logs?

Comment: It is empty nothing is showing up there. Do i need to add anything extra so something shows up there

Comment: Did you add the StartFromBeginning after working with the Function at some point? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions#need-to-restart-and-re-process-all-the-items-in-my-container-from-the-beginning